# How can I show info about created extension in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I've read this https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Extensions and tried to make an extension and I have a simple question:

- How can i show user the info (what parameters, etc) about extension when he writes `create extension *extensionname*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that is the correct place for documentation, but you could ad a `DO` statement to the SQL script:

```
DO $$BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE 'Please read the documentation.";
END;$$;
```